# Takes at least 2 refreshes to load a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm

Website is hosted on Firebase.

But the issue is, whenever we go to the website, let's say `www.website.com` we need to refresh it at least twice in order to load the website.

---

### Update:

Not sure what possibly could be the issue

1. Using Firebase Hosting to host our website, we have a custom URL where it's being re-routed to. (`*1`)
2. `npm run build` to create production build
3. deploying via `firebase deploy`

---

### Problem:

User tries to open the page in the 1st try it loads nothing but can see the following error:

> `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <               firebase-app.js:1`

In the 2nd try the page loads correctly.

As listed by Frank in the comments it's not an issue from Firebase then is it something from React (Create-React-App)?

---

### References:

`*1` - Have tried both routes, custom route and route provided by Firebase hosting, and the issue happens in both.

Comment: Try to access it by using the default firebase url. Then try to see if there is any dependency taking too long to load. And then contact support.

Comment: @cutiko, tried doing that, shows a blank page at first load. Once I refresh it works.

Comment: Sometimes we don't clearly know what the problem is, this is one of that situation. Usually, I ask questions with very precise and accurate examples followed by hints and my attempts, but in this situation, I'm quite unaware. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Did you try what? Using the default URL or searching for slow dependencies? @Dhaval Jardosh

Comment: I was routing from firebase hosted url to my custom URL. So I assume you meant that I should be using the firebase url instead of my custom URL to check if it loads at the first go, but that's not happening as well. I try to load my page with my URL at first it shows a blank white page and upon refresh, it renders everything.

Comment: Without seeing how to reproduce the problem all I can say is that I don't have that problem on any of the sites I have on Firebase Hosting.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Have u tried disabling cache in the network tab of the developer console?

Comment: @SahilGupta, this behavior is uncertain. Sometimes it happens and sometimes it works fine. I tried your suggestion and at the moment it worked every time. But do I need to do this on a client device? Or is there any other way?

Comment: No i think you don't have to do this on client device. I think this was caused due to caching. You can check whether this works without disabling caching in an incognito tab. If that works, then it a caching issue which would not be created on client devices.

Comment: Ok, let me try a few times and will give you an update. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey can you give us some link to the site? The problem may be something else that I can sniff just for looking at headers or chrome network tab !

Comment: can u show me a screenshot of your files root? open the `build` folder and include it on the screenshot, I will also need the url where you app is... a few others have been reporting this error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably your problem is that some of the resources are cached. If you reload once the browser will only reload the main url. If you reload twice other resources will be refreshed. So it can be some strange behaviour derived from this.

There are some tricks, for example if you can change the url of the js file, change it from http://yoursite/folder/file.js to http://yoursite/folder/file.js?_=TIMESTAMP where TIMESTAMP is a timestamp, got for example from new Date().getTime() on js or time() on php (every language has a way for getting a timestamp). That _ parameter will invalidate the cache. If this works there are more elegant ways to tell the browser to handle caches according to your needs.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'm not sure which file name I need to do modification to.

Comment: Usually the problem is in the JS.
However check everything: open browser debug's panel (F12) and go to the network tab before first loading to enable it.
After the first loading check both network tab resources list and the code (html tag + right button + copy external) and paste it in a file comparator like winmerge.
Reload the second time (when everything works) and repeat the process, paste the other source html external source and the network resources list in the other side of the comparator. Check the differences.

Comment: Also remember that the cache control headers solution is better in the longterm than the ?_=NNN solution.

Comment: @user1039663 do we need to change the chunk.js files in index.html in build folder and can we do this by package when app is created with create-react-app

Answer (score 4):

### Service Workers

If you're using `create-react-app`, the problem is that there is a service worker that is likely caching the page for offline use. Service workers were enabled by default until CRA v2.0 (which is different versioning from `react-scripts`). It can take a few reloads to get the fresh content because the service worker, which is persisting in the browser between reloads, is what is actually hitting your hosting service to look for new content. By default, it always loads instantly from cache, until it has a chance to hit the server to check for new content. By default, the browser's console will output once you've been on a stale web page for a few seconds with `New content available! Please reload.`. The next refresh pulls the new content into the browser's cache.

#### Disable on a Specific Browser (locally)

If you just want to turn it off for development in Chrome, once you have your website loaded, you can go into the `dev tools>Application>Service Workers`. Once you're there, there are several checkboxes for the service worker for that website. You can check `Update on reload` and `Bypass for network`.

#### Disable Globally

However, if you want to permanently disable service workers, you have to unregister them first from all existing registered users. If you just remove the file called `service-worker.js`, it will not unregister it for users who have already accessed your site, which is problematic. In order to remove the service worker from clients who have already accessed your site, you'll have to unregister it. In your `index.js` file at the root of the `src` folder, you need to change this

```
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
registerServiceWorker();
```

to

```
import { unregister } from './registerServiceWorker';
unregister();
```

What you are doing is preventing it from further registering service workers (by removing the `registerServiceWorker` function) and unregistering any existing service workers by calling the `unregister` function. The service worker might be on any number of browsers, so it's best to unregister, instead of only removing the `registerServiceWorker` function.

You can read more about service workers on the `create-react-app` [docs site](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app). 
Here's a [link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2715) to the github issue in which the authors of CRA explain how to disable the service worker.